# How often have dust devils saved a Martian lander or rover?

Tags: mars, history, rovers, solar-power, lander

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48128/12102) to *How are the Mars Rovers maintained?* reminds us that

> ...much to the surprise of the early Mars scientists and rover teams, Mars takes care of the dust problem for us! Mars' typical weather generates these dust devils that whip through periodically and clean off the solar panels, thus giving new life to the rovers every time.

**Question:** How often have dust devil events made a significant improvement in a Martian lander or rover's ability to operate?

---

related:

- [Curiosity is still dirty! How will the ExoMARS Rover keep its solar panels dust-free and collecting sufficient power?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18262/12102)
- [Brushing clean a Mars lander's solar panels](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32445/12102)

Comment: The March 9, 2005 Spirit event is likely the only one.