# What does it mean when a software is called open-source for US-release only?

Tags: nasa, software, regulatory, classified, open-source

I saw [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23082/12102) about MarsGRAM, and when I clicked on the [NASA software link](https://software.nasa.gov/software/MFS-33158-1) to read about it I saw at the bottom of the page a blurb for [EarthGRAM 2010](https://software.nasa.gov/software/MFS-32780-1), an atmospheric model for Earth with likely [all kinds of insight](https://see.msfc.nasa.gov/model-gram) beyond a simple scale heigh or scale height modified by temperature spherical model.

I was happy to see "open-source", as well as the easy-to-read and transcribe "FORTRAN" language.

But at the bottom it says "U.S. Release Only" and I am living overseas.

**Question:** *What does it mean when a software is called open-source for US-release only?* What are the rules exactly? Does this refer to the location of download, or of use, or to the citizenship of the person requesting the software?

So far I have not been able to find out what the restrictions really are. I've cycled through a few links but so far without initiating a request for the software, I am not sure how to view the restrictions on eligibility.

[image]

Comment: Re *easy-to-read and transcribe "FORTRAN"* -- Apparently uou forgot to use the <sarcasm> ... </sarcasm> tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what the [NASA Software FAQ](https://software.nasa.gov/faq) says:

> The release type determines who can have a NASA software code. If you meet the access criteria for the code (as defined below), NASA can transfer the software to you.
>   Release types:
>
> General Public Release: For codes with a broad release and no nondisclosure or export control restrictions
>
> Open Source Release: For collaborative efforts in which programmers improve upon codes originally developed by NASA and share the changes
>
> **U.S. Release Only: For codes available to U.S. persons only**
>
> U.S. and Foreign Release: For codes that are available to U.S. persons and persons outside of the U.S. (who meet certain export control restrictions)
>
> U.S. Government Purpose Release: For codes that are to be used on behalf of the U.S. government by a federal agency or business/university under a federal contract/grant/agreement.

<sup>emphasis added</sup>

In case that is not clear, here is the definition of a U.S. person from the [University of Pittsburgh Office of Research](http://www.research.pitt.edu/exco-us-person-vs-foreign-person):

> U.S. Person (EAR Part 772 and ITAR 120.15)
>   Pursuant to the EAR and the ITAR, a U.S. Person includes :
>
> any individual who is granted U.S. citizenship; or
>
> any individual who is granted U.S. permanent residence ("Green Card" holder); or
>
> any individual who is granted status as a "protected person" under 8 U.S.C. 1324b(a)(3);
>
> any corporation/business/organization/group incorporated in the United States under U.S. law;
>
> any part of U.S. government.

You will note that the page for Earth-GRAM has a request link instead of a download link. That is how they check to ensure you qualify to receive the release.

Comment: OK this is very helpful, thank you! It sounds like it refers to the individual, not to the physical location. I understand that clicking the request link sets in motion a verification process and it is not a download button. I was not able to find this kind of guidance by clicking any of the links on the pages associated with EarthGRAM; I didn't know there was a general NASA software FAQ site - very helpful answer!

Comment: I wonder, with this being open source, what are the redistribution restrictions?

Comment: @SF. We'd have to see the license.

Comment: @SF. -- It means it's not really open source, at least not by any reasonable concept of what "open source" means. A recipient needs to get approval from NASA before distributing it to others. If the software happens to get outside of the US, the recipient who gave/sold the software to the exporting party may be subject to ITAR/EAR regulations. This means time in jail and/or a huge fine.