# Looking for atmospheric density models of various planets and moons

Tags: reentry, atmosphere

Looking for atmospheric density models of various planets and moons, any sort of data/resources/database of this information would be extremely useful as I am working on recreating these models for simulations.

Comment: Please use good grammar it will get you better answers and less down votes. Read everything!. Happy to see a new user.

Comment: Maybe a few more specifications could help.. do you just need an atmospheric scale height for a simple exponential density model, or do you need something more sophisticated?

Comment: It would help to know what level of detail you're looking for.  For example, here's a paper with some nice work on the hydrogen density of Ganymede: https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/97GL01927

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs, a simple exponential model could work. A list of [various body's scale heights is available on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height#Planetary_examples).

At the opposite extreme, there are [the GRAMs](https://software.nasa.gov/search/multi/aw/software/9/gram), Global Reference Atmospheric Model(s). These are the gold standard of atmospheric modeling ([short of a few use cases](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23082/40257)), available for all bodies with significant atmospheres (Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Titan, Uranus, Neptune).

You do have to officially request access to the GRAM software(s) from NASA and sign a "Software Usage Agreement" (*cool or frightening or verbosely bureaucratic depending on how you look at it*), but in my experience the process was pretty easy and relatively quick (a few days).